# ASP.NET Ajax Get Takes too long time

Tags: ajax, model-view-controller

I have an asp.net mvc project. I am getting some questions and answers for questions from database by ajax get. My query takes too long. How can i edit my code to work faster?

I am storing my questions and answers seperate tables. Each answer is related questions by ids.

Thanks for answers.

My view:

```
 $.ajax({//GET QUESTIONS
                url: '@Url.Action("GetQuestionsBySubCategory", "Order")',
                type: "GET",
                data: { subcattext : selectedSubCategory },
                success: function (result) {

                    $('<div class=\"form-group\" id=\"sorularform\" ><input name=\"altcat\" value=\"' + selectedSubCategory + '\" type=\"hidden\">').prependTo("#sorular");

                        // loop each question
                    for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
                        //IF QUESTION 1 START
                        if (result[i].QuestionType == 1) {
                            $('<label for=\"exampleFormControlSelect' + i + '\" > ' + result[i].Description + '</label ><select name=\"' + result[i].Description + ' \" class=\"form-control\" id=\"exampleFormControlSelect' + result[i].Id + '\"></select>').appendTo("#sorularform");

                            var questionid;
                          $.ajax({//GET ANSWERS
                            url: '@Url.Action("GetAnswersByQuestionId", "Order")',
                              type: "GET",
                              data: { questionid: result[i].Id },
                                success: function (answerresult) {
                                    for (var a = 0; a < answerresult.length; a++) {
                                        $('<option>' + answerresult[a].Description + '</option>').prependTo("#exampleFormControlSelect" + answerresult[a].Question_Id);
                                    }

                            },
                            error: function (err) {
                                // the call thrown an error
                                console.log("Hata Oluştu")
                            },
                            complete: function () {
                                //$(".loading").hide();

                            }
                        });

                        };

                        }
                },
                error: function (err) {
                    // the call thrown an error
                    console.log("Hata Oluştu")

                },
                complete: function () {
                    //$(".loading").hide();
                    $("</div>").appendTo(".form-group");
                    $('#yersec').insertBefore('#sorularform');

                    //$('#sorular').html(table);

                }
            });
```

Controller.cs

```
 public ActionResult GetQuestionsBySubCategory(string subcattext)
    {
        var subcatid = subCategoryServices.GetAll().Where(x => x.Title == subcattext).FirstOrDefault().Id;
        IEnumerable<QuestionVM> questionList = questionServices.GetAll().Where(x => x.SubCategory_Id == subcatid);

        return Json(questionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult GetAnswersByQuestionId(int questionid)
    {

        IEnumerable<AnswerVM> answerList = answerServices.GetAll().Where(x => x.Question_Id == questionid);

        return Json(answerList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

Comment: Make your database faster.

Comment: Or change your code to actually filter in the database.

Comment: Why are you calling the `GetAll()` method of your service? It probably returns all the rows from the database hence the slow request.

Comment: And also the way that you are appending in every iteration on your client side code is also expensive.

Comment: @Hackerman I think so

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your querying faster, I would recommend Dapper. Dapper is a lightweight ORM that runs almost as fast as native SQL. There is a good tutorial that I would recommend you reading here: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/asp-net-mvc-crud-with-dapper-micro-orm/

Essentially, you'll be running queries like this (this isn't exact but it's very close to the Dapper syntax without seeing your database structure or the rest of your code):

```
public ActionResult GetQuestionsBySubCategory(string subcattext)
{
    var subcatid = db.Query("SELECT Id from SubcategoryServices WHERE Title = @title", new { title = subcattext });
    IEnumerable<QuestionVM> questionList = db.Query("SELECT * FROM QuestionServices WHERE SubCategory_Id = @subcategoryId", new { subcategoryId = subcatid });

    return Json(questionList, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

**Aside** - your DOM manipulation is *very* slow too, so that could also be making your application slower too. The technical reason is because the DOM has to re-render itself once you append elements to it. Rendering takes time.

It is out of the scope to create your whole application here, but I would *strongly* recommend at [ReactJs](https://reactjs.org/) or [Vue](https://vuejs.org/) as front-end libraries to create faster frontend code.

Comment: I am using Entity Framework Generic Repository pattern.

Comment: That is still fine. Within your class that implements the repository interface you created, instead of using Entity Framework, you would use Dapper to retrieve data from your database

Comment: I think my frontend code is expensive. I have 200 questions and 600 answers. This numbers not problem for EF

Comment: Yes, I would recommend you use ReactJS for your front end, otherwise your browser is re-rendering 800 elements which will **definitely** slow it down